# Javascript Autocomplete suggestions placed above the input field

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, keyboard

I am using google.maps.places.Autocomplete in my mobile app as part of an input field at the bottom of the screen.  when the user focuses on the input field the virtual keyboard appears shortening the app in order to fit the keyboard.  When this happens though the places.Autocomplete suggestions appear beneath the keyboard.  Obviously, you don't want to place the suggestions in front of the keyboard because then the keys are obstructed.

My thought is to place the suggestions above the input field but I can't figure out how to do this.  It appears this is possible but I haven't found a coherent way to manage this problem.  I am using Javascript (haven't converted to jQuery yet - yes, I know, let the flaming begin).

Is there another way to manage this problem so the suggestions aren't covered by the keyboard?

Comment: Can't you put the search box on top of the app?

Comment: Technically yes I could.  However there is already a search box at the top.  The top one is for the From address...then the map takes up the bulk of the screen...and the TO address input box is at the bottom.  So for aesthetics and flow it looks good like this.

Answer (score 0):

add margin to the search suggestions box

```
.pac-container{
  margin-top: - 200px
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<code><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var input = document.getElementById('searchLocations');  
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Add a input field name **searchLocations** in body section.
Thank you
sumon

Comment: it's looking for API keys